# Python 3 и (PyGobject или РyGTK или PyGI)

Tags: python, gtk, wxpython, gnome, pygtk

Какое окружение использовать в Python 3 для кроссплатформенности.
Охота что бы лучше дружила с Windows, поддерживала бы Gnome 3.X и безболезненно могла портироваться на MacOS. Кто с чем ел при таких обстоятельствах.... Хочу разработать кроссплатформенное приложение... Слышал что PyGTK для Python 2.7 и больше развиваться не будет. А мне надо под Третью версию. Помогите.

Answer (score 1):

PyGObject for Windows
http://sourceforge.net/projects/pygobjectwin32/files/?source=navbar

PyGObject (aka PyGI)
https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/PyGObject

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?